# Mysql: get IPv6 binary net mask from binary ip and subnet

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ipv6, bitwise-operators

I have a table that stores IPv6 addresses as BINARY(16) and subnet as INT(3)

I thought it would be simple to get the net mask by doing:

```
SELECT ~INET6_ATON('::') << (128 - subnet);
```

but this returns zero, in fact all the bitwise operators seem to deliver integer results when I use them on a binary string :-(

I'm using 10.1.30-MariaDB

```
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.30-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
```

any help much appreciated.

EDIT: I completely misinterpreted Maria's version string, sorry :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit operations in 5.5 are limited to 64 bits.  (8.0 relaxes the limitation.
5.5 is getting quite old.  If you upgrade, either dump and reload, or upgrade in 3 steps: 5.5->5.6->5.7->8.0)

You probably wanted a *right* shift `>>`.  Or maybe `(1 << amt) - 1`.  Example (using only 64-bit arithmetic):

```
SELECT HEX(~((1 << 8) - 1)); --> FFFFFFFFFFFFFF00
```

Some 128-bit operations are available in the "reference implementation for IPv6" link from http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges .  There is not a "shift" function, but you could adapt the techniques (that use `HEX()`) to achieve your purpose.  It does have add/subtract 1 to/from an IPv6 value.  This is handy for certain mask-building and masking operations.

If you would like to explain what you will be doing with the result of that `SELECT`, I might be able to give you more of an answer.

(Found in the 5.7.11 release notes):

> Bit functions and operators comprise [BIT_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count), [BIT_AND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and), [BIT_OR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or), [BIT_XOR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-xor), [&](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and), [|](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or), [^](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor), [~](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-invert), [<<](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift), and [>>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_right-shift). Currently, bit functions and operators require [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) (64-bit integer) arguments and return [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) values, so they have a maximum range of 64 bits. Arguments of other types are converted to [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) and truncation might occur.
>
> An extension for MySQL 8.0 changes this cast-to-[BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) behavior: Bit functions and operators permit binary string type arguments ([BINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html), [VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html), and the [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) types), enabling them to take arguments and produce return values larger than 64 bits. Consequently, bit operations on binary string arguments in MySQL 5.7 might produce different results in MySQL 8.0. To provide advance notice about this potential change in behavior, the server now produces warnings for bit operations for which binary string arguments are not converted to integer in MySQL 8.0. These warnings afford an opportunity to rewrite affected statements. To explicitly produce MySQL 5.7 behavior in a way that will not change after an upgrade to 8.0, cast bit-operation binary string arguments to convert them to integer. For more information and examples, see [Bit Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

Comment: Sorry, I read the version string wrong. Its Maria 10, so bitwise operations on 128-bit strings should be possible?

Comment: @underscorePez - MariaDB 10.1 corresponds, roughly to MySQL 5.6.  I am pretty sure it still has a 64-bit limit on the necessary bit operations.